# What is linq to sql query for problim below?

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I have a table which has shipment id and clientid; I want to have the count of shipmentid associated with each client id as result. What is linq for that?

Comment: Can you please clarify your question with more information?

Comment: The table consists of two fields ClientID and ShipID shipId is primary key and a clientID can have multiple shipid's .i  want to have query that returns count of shipid's  along with the associated clientid and select top two results from the result.how can i do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The table consists of two fields ClientID and ShipID shipId is primary
>   key and a clientID can have multiple shipid's .i want to have query
>   that returns count of shipid's along with the associated clientid and
>   select top two results from the result.how can i do that? –

You could try something like this:

```
var result = db.shipmentClient
               .GroupBy(sc=>sc.clientId)
               .Select(gr=>new 
               {
                   ClientId = gr.Key(),
                   Shipments = gr.Count()
               })
               .OrderByDescending(x=>x.Shipments)
               .Take(2);
```

I suppose that `db` is your database context class and shipmentClient is the name of your table. If so, you can make a group by like above based on the ClientId and then count how many shipments are associated with a client. Then your order the results and you select the top two results.